# Discord.js, detect if there's a message sent by a certain user?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I'm messing around with creating a discord bot that repeatedly pings a user until they respond/say anything in the chat (annoying, right?). The amount of times to ping the user and the time between each ping can also be adjusted if necessary. However, I can't seem to find a way to detect if the pinged user actually says something in the chat, and a way to stop the loop.

The actual pinging part of the code is in this for loop:

```
const ping = async () => {
            for(var i = 1; i <= pingAmount; i++){

                //the wait() command
                await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, pingTime * 1000));

                //the actual ping
                message.channel.send(`hey <@${userID}> let\'s play minecraft`);

            }

            //sends a message once pinging is finished
            message.channel.send("Pinging Complete.");

        };
```

I've tried nesting the following code inside that loop, but I get no results.

```
                client.on('message', message =>{
                    if(message.author == taggedUser) {
                        message.channel.send('User has replied. Stopping pings.')
                        return;
                    }
                });
```

Any help is appreciated!

full code below:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'Ping',
    description: "Pings specified user until they appear",
    execute(message, args, Discord){

        //initialize variables

        const client = new Discord.Client();

        const taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first();

        const userID = message.mentions.users.first().id;

        //splits the command

        const slicedString = message.content.split(' ');

        //grabs specific numbers from command as input

        const pingAmount = slicedString.slice(4,5);

        const pingTime = slicedString.slice(5);


        //display confirmation info in chat

        message.channel.send(`So, ${message.author.username}, you want to annoy ${taggedUser.username}? Alright then lol`);
        message.channel.send(`btw ${taggedUser.username}\'s user ID is ${userID} lmao`);
        message.channel.send(`amount of times to ping: ${pingAmount}`);
        message.channel.send(`time between pings: ${pingTime} seconds`);

        //checks to make sure pingTime isnt too short

        if(pingTime < 5){
            if(pingTime == 1){
                message.channel.send(`1 second is too short!`);
                return;
            } else {
                message.channel.send(`${pingTime} seconds is too short!`);
                return;
            }
        }

        //timer and loop using pingAmount and pingTime as inputs

        const ping = async () => {
            for(var i = 1; i <= pingAmount; i++){

                //the wait() command
                await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, pingTime * 1000));

                //the actual ping
                message.channel.send(`hey <@${userID}> let\'s play minecraft`);


                const pingedUsers = [taggedUser];
                // doodle message
                const msg = {author: {id:1}};

                // message event
                const onMessage = (message) => {
                if (pingedUsers.indexOf(message.author.id) != -1) {
                console.log("user replied");
                }
                }

                onMessage(msg); // nothing
                pingedUsers.push(msg.author.id); // push the author id
                onMessage(msg); // he replied!
                

            }

            //sends a message once pinging is finished
            message.channel.send("Pinging Complete.");

        };

        //runs the ping function
        ping();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be comparing the author's snowflake (id) in this case.
You can put the pinged users in a list and see if the message author is in that list.

```js
const pingedUsers = [];
// doodle message
const msg = {author: {id:1}};

// message event
const onMessage = (message) => {
  if (pingedUsers.indexOf(message.author.id) != -1) {
    console.log("user replied");
  }
}

onMessage(msg); // nothing
pingedUsers.push(msg.author.id); // push the author id
onMessage(msg); // he replied!
```

Comment: I tried adding that code into the loop and setting the pingedUsers to the id of the taggedUser, but instead of printing to the console whenever that specific user says something, it prints every time that user is tagged by the bot. I think there's just something i don't understand here.

Comment: @Joodoon is your loop inside your message event listener aka .on

Comment: just edited my original post to include my full code—hopefully this clarifies the problem. I don't think I have an event listener so that might be the issue? How would I go about implementing that into my code? thanks again for the help